# Pre-rendering a canvas rectangle with text, is this bad performance?

Tags: javascript, canvas

It is taking up to 0.300ms to complete which is at least 2X slower than just caling the function straight without pre-rendering, I think thats quite a lot... What do you guys think? Is this normal? Am I doing this right? Something must be wrong.

```
function complexDraw(ctx){
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
    ctx.fillRect(90 * Xf, 380 * Yf, 200 * Xf, 30 * Yf);//k10
    ctx.fillStyle = "White";
    ctx.font = pixels + "px monospace";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText("Left: " + currentremain, 185 * Xf, 400 * Yf);
}

function cloneCanvas(oldCanvas) {

    //create a new canvas
    var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');

    //set dimensions
    newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;
    newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height;

    //apply the old canvas to the new one
    context.drawImage(oldCanvas, 0, 0);

    //return the new canvas
    return newCanvas;
}

var cacheCanvas = cloneCanvas(a_canvas); // newCanvas
var cacheCtx = cacheCanvas.getContext('2d'); // context


var draw = function draw(){
    complexDraw(cacheCtx); //updates text each time
    ctx.drawImage(cacheCanvas,0,0);
}

console.time("new");
draw();
console.timeEnd("new")// 0.300ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still doing the drawing on your "cache" canvas so essentially you are doing the drawing + copy. I wouldn't be surprised if it takes more then just drawing directly. Especially if your canvases are large and you have to copy loads of pixels.

**Edit:** Just to clarify: You do not need to implement double buffering for HTML canvas because browsers do not update canvas image on screen until your script is finished executing.

Comment: I do not quite understand, am I not supposed to draw the image on a cached canvas, then copy the image?

Comment: You should if your every drawing function goes directly to the screen via OS and hardware. Then drawing directly to the screen may be slower and also show "flickering". Then drawing on in memory bitmap and just flushing it to screen when finished would be faster and also remove flickering as all image would be refreshed at once. However in JavaScript I think browser is smart enough to postpone real changes to the screen till after your script is finished executing.

Comment: the ctx.drawImage(cacheCanvas,0,0); is so expensive to fire